# Why are the quantities equal to 0?

Tags: optimization, simplex

I am looking at the general form of the Simplex algorithm with the use of tableaux.

$\overline{x_0}$ is a basic non degenarate feasible solution and thus the columns $P_1, \dots, P_m$ are linearly independent.

The first step is to create a $(m+1) \times (n+4)$ matrix as follows:

- At the first column we write the basic columns: $P_1, \dots, P_m$.
- At the second column we write the values of the corresponding coefficients of the objective funtion.
- At the third column we write the initial basic feasible non degenerate solution $\overline{x_0}$.
- At the next $n$ columns we write the elements of the columns of the matrix $A$.
- The last column remains empty for now.
- At the last row we write the value $z_0$ of the objective function that corresponds to the solution $\overline{x_0}$ and also the values of the differences $z_k-c_k, k=1, \dots, n$

**Remark**

The value of $z_k$ is the dot product of the second and the $(3+k)$-th column.

Why does it hold that $z_1-c_1=0, \dots, z_m-c_m=0$ ?

Isn't it $z_1-c_1=c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0+ \dots + c_m \cdot z_m=c_1$? Or am I wrong?

**EDIT**: Also, suppose that we are given the following linear programming problem:

$$\max (5x_1-4x_2) \\ x_1-x_2+x_3=6 \\ 3x_1-2x_2+x_4=24 \\ -2x_1+3x_2+x_5=9 \\ x_1 \geq 0, i=1, \dots, 5$$

The first tableau is this:

$$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b  & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & \theta \\ 
P_3 & 0 & 6 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 24 & 3 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\ 
P_5 & 0 & 9 & -2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\ 
 & z & 0 & -5 & 4 &  0& 0 & 0 & 
\end{matrix}$$

How did we deduce that $z_1-c_1=-5$ ?

Comment: A very good example is given here : http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c09s3.pdf , I'll keep looking at this problem

Answer (score 0):

$Why\ does\ it\ hold\ that\ z_1-c_1=0, \dots, z_m-c_m=0? \tag{Q1}$
$Isn't\ it\ z_1-c_1=c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0+ \dots + c_m \cdot z_m=c_1? \ Or\ am\ I\ wrong? \tag{Q2}$
$How\ did\ we\ deduce\ that\ z_1−c_1=−5 ? \tag{Q3}$

$(A3)$: The $z$ row only has non zero entries for non basic variables,  $x_1,x_2$. The cost function is $\max (5x_1-4x_2)$. When a pivot is performed only a $1$ is left in a basic variable column note columns $P_3,P_4,P_5$. Pivoting changes the $z$ values.

$(A1)$: The $z$ value of a basic variable is always zero. It is zeroed when a pivot occurs.

$(A2)$: $z_k$ is the result of a row reduction during the pivoting process.

There is a very good example at [Tableau example](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c09s3.pdf)

---

Q: "Also wh does it hold that the $z$ value of a basic variable is always zero?"

Given:

\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b  & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & \theta \\ 
P_3 & 0 & 6 & \color{red}{1} & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 24 & 3 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\ 
P_5 & 0 & 9 & -2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\ 
 & z & 0 & \color{red}{-5} & 4 &  0& 0 & 0 & 
\end{matrix}

To select $P_1$ as a basic variable and remove $P_3$

$RowZ :=  RowZ + 5*Row1$

\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b  & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & \theta \\ 
P_3 & 0 & 6 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 24 & 3 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\ 
P_5 & 0 & 9 & -2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\ 
 & z & 30 & 0 & -1 &  5 & 0 & 0 & 
\end{matrix}

Continuing to reduce all the entries in the $P_!$ column to zero except for the top:

\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b  & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & \theta \\ 
P_1 & \color{red}{5} & 6 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 1 & -3 & 1 & 0 & \\ 
P_5 & 0 & 21 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & \\ 
 & z & 30 & 0 & -1 &  5 & 0 & 0 & 
\end{matrix}

There is only a $1$ left in the $P_1$ column after the reduction and $z_1$ was reduced to zero.

The $z_k$ values are the coefficients of the cost function for the set of non basic variables.

---

$C_k$? : I don't know why you need this column?. The $z$ row keeps track of the coefficients of the cost function with respect to the non basic variables. Only $x_1$ and $x_2$ contribute to the cost.

Perhaps I'm not clear about the definition of the $c_B$ column?

---

Comment: Could you explain me further how we deduce that $z_1-c_1=-5$ ? Also wh does it hold that the $z$ value of a basic variable is always zero? @arthur

Comment: In general how do we compute $z_k-c_k$ ? I haven't understood yet...

Comment: Perhaps I'm not clear about the definition of the $c_B$ column?

Comment: The $0$s mean that at the objective function the coefficients  of $x_3, x_4, x_5$ are equal to zero.

Comment: For $x_1$ $c_{x_1} = 5$ and for $x_2$ $c_{x_2} = -4$ , there is no equation with $z_k$. $z_k$ is produced by row reductions.

Comment: You mean that we look for a pivot and then we find $z_k-c_k$ ? But then how can we know if the initial feasible non degenerate solution is the optimal one?

Comment: I learnt tableau from the book "Numerical Recipes in C"  it does not have a $c_B$ column. Is there a web link to an explanation or example?

Comment: You have an optimal solution when all $z_k \ge 0$

Comment: I haven't found a link.  $z_j$ is defined as follows.

$$z_j:= x_{1j} c_1+x_{2j} c_2+ \dots +x_{mj} c_m$$

I thought that it would hold $z_1-c_1=(5,-4,0,0,0) \cdot (0,0,1,3,-2)$ but then we wouldn't get $-5$. Do you maybe have an idea how else we deduce that $z_1-c_1=-5$? @arthur

Comment: I don't understand where $-c_1$ comes from? In the $z_j$ equation I don't know where $x_{kj}$ come from.  The initial $z_j$ values come from the cost function $\max (5x_1-4x_2)$. For some reason they reverse the sign to give $-5\, +4$ then pivot to get all $z_k \ge 0$. When the cost function $f = const  -a_gx_g -a_hx_h \dots$ where all $a_k \ge 0$. At this point swapping any non basic variable can only reduce $f$ so a maximum is reached.

Comment: $x_{kj}$ in the $z_j$ equation are given in the formula:

$$P_j=x_{1j} P_1+ x_{2j} P_2+ \dots + x{mj} P_j$$

Comment: Are you not convinced that the $z_k$ value of a basic variable is always zero? It is deliberately  reduced to zero when a pivot occurs. The $z_k$ values of non basic variables just come out in the row reduction during the pivot.

Comment: If $z_k$ is the value of a basic variable shouldn't one coefficient be non-zero, i.e. the one that corresponds to the corresponding basic variable? Or am I wrong? @arthur

Comment: Sorry, I should have written that $z_k$ is the weight of the variable in the cost function, not the value of the variable.

Comment: So could you explain me how we calculate for example $z_1$ at the example that I have written at my initial post?

Comment: The total cost is $z$, $z = b_z - z_1x_1 -z_2x_2 -z_3x_3 \dots$. The initial cost is $z = 5x_1 - 4x_2$ from $\max (5x_1-4x_2)$. So $z_1 = -5$ and $z_2 = 4$, $b_z = 0$ all other $z_k = 0$. The $z$ row are the weights of  the cost function in the non basic variables. All basic variable weights are zero.